# How to display records from a data extension on a cloud page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, lookup, data

I am trying to display some records from data extension on a cloud page.

This is what I got so far but cloud page is showing nothing.

*Note: "LU" is a field in my data extension with value 1 for records that needs to be  displayed*

```
 %%[

var @FieldA, @FieldB, @row, @rows, @rowCount, @i

set @rows = LookupRows("EmailJobsDE","LU","1")

set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
set @FieldA = field(@row,"JobID")
set @FieldB = field(@row,"EmailName")

]%%

    %%=v(@FieldA)=%% | %%=v(@FieldB)=%%

%%[ 

next @i 

endif

]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

The script is right. I don't see any issues with this. Sometimes cloud page does not show the changes right away, it may take a few minutes to show the updated result. If possible please check your Data Extension as well just to be double sure.

I have replicated your script -

```
%%[
var @FieldA, @FieldB, @row, @rows, @rowCount, @i
set @rows = LookupRows("DE_Lookup_test", "LU", "1")
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
set @FieldA = field(@row,"JobID")
set @FieldB = field(@row,"EmailName")
]%%
    %%=v(@FieldA)=%% | %%=v(@FieldB)=%% <br>
%%[ 
next @i 
endif
]%%
```

And got the results on the cloud page -

45678 | Test456
67890 | Test678

Comment: Hi Mradul, the cloud page is not showing anything., I have already cleared browser cache / history and refreshed / re-published / re-tested the page.

Comment: @kuml2 updated my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.